# I want strip argument from variable args by using template meta programming

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates

I am new to template meta programming. I want to strip args from variable argument in c++. I am making a function which will `push_back()` element to any type of container. Its very easy to do in C++ 17 but i want to provide support for C++ 11 . Please find the code below `push_back()` function implementation i am looking for. Please avoid `va_start()`, `va_end()` c style solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template<class Container, class T, class... Args>
void push_back(Container& con, T tail, Args... args);

template<class T>
T get_tail(T data) {
    return data;
}

template<class T, class ...Args>
T get_tail(T& tail, Args&... args) {
    return tail;
}

template<class Container , class T,class... Args>
void push_back(Container& con, T tail,Args... args ) {
        //C++ 17 ((con.push_back(args), ...);
    con.push_back(tail);
    std::cout << (tail) << std::endl;
    T newTail = get_tail(args...);
    push_back(con,newTail,args...); 
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
bool pair_comparer(T a, T b, Args... args) {
    return a == b && pair_comparer(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v_int;
    push_back(v_int,1,2,3,4 );
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    for (auto iter = v_int.begin(); iter != v_int.begin(); iter++) {
        std::cout << "=== " << *iter << " ===" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an error in the code: `iter != v_int.begin()` instead of `iter != v_int.end()`. The best remedy is using range-based `for`: less typing, less errors and available in C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but...

Are you sure you need recursion?

You can develop something similar the C++17 way unpacking the variadic `args...`, using the initialization of an unused C-style array, as follows

```
template <typename Container, typename ... Args>
void push_back (Container & con, Args ... args ) {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, ((void)con.push_back(args), std::cout << args << std::endl, 0)... };
}
```

Or simply as follows

```
template <typename Container, typename ... Args>
void push_back (Container & con, Args ... args ) {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, ((void)con.push_back(args), 0)... };
}
```

if the `std::cout` part is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: I think there will be issue if type is class which have deleted operator [] ?

Comment: @Mohit: `Args::operator[]` is not used, issue might happen with evil types overloading operator comma. so currently, for return type of `con.push_back(args)`. casting to void solves the issue anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42 - given that `con` is a container, I hope nobody is so evil to overload comma operator but... to be sure... `(void)` added; thanks.

Comment: @max66 Thanks ,you are correct but i am going through some cases update you as i need to check the type safety and inheritance,run time polymorphic behavior  .

Comment: Hello Max i am not able to understand how  unused array is working can you send any reference where i can read about that ?Thanks

Comment: @Mohit - Reference? No idea. Anyway, the function of the C-style array is just to give a place (it's initialization list) where you can expand the parameter pack `args...` (trough `con.push_back(args)...`). You have to take also in count the comma operator (after `push_back()`) that compute but discard the element on left (`push_back()`) and return the element on the right (the zero). So you have a C-style array of integer initialized with zeros but the execution of the `push_back()` for all `args...`.

Answer (score 2):

You've already stripped the first argument away when you did

```
void push_back(Container& con, T tail, Args... args ) {
```

`tail` is the first argument and `args` is the rest, so your recursive call at the end simply needs to say

```
pus_back(con, args...)
```

No need for any of this `get_tail` hackery. Then, simply have another overload of `push_back` that looks like this.

```
template <class Container>
void push_back(Container& con) {
  // A whole lot of nothing happens here...
}
```

That handles the base case, and the function you already wrote (with the one minor modification) handles the recursive case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you call `push_back` inside of itself with the *same* number of arguments. This makes the recursion infinite. Instead you need to "strip" one argument each time. And certainly provide the recursion base. Like this:

```
template<class Container>
void push_back(Container& con) {
}

template<class Container , class T,class... Args>
void push_back(Container& con, T tail, Args... args ) {
    con.push_back(tail);
    std::cout << (tail) << std::endl;
    push_back(con, args...);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v_int;
    push_back(v_int,1,2,3,4 );
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    for (auto x : v_int)
        std::cout << "=== " << x << " ===" << std::endl;
}
```